# Trail renderer always black?

Tags: unity-game-engine

For some reason the 2D trail renderer stays black no matter what I do to change the color. Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the tail renderer needs a sprite shader. You are using a standard shader so lighting will be calculated wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is very easy. You use *Mobile/Diffuse* shader that does not accept *Main Color* to multiply the texture. You need shader that has *Main Color*. You can use my (it is varation of *Mobile/Diffuse* but with *Main Color*)

```
    Shader "Mobile/Diffuse Color" {
    Properties {
        // Adds Color field we can modify
        _Color ("Main Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)        
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass {
            Lighting Off

            SetTexture [_MainTex] { 
                // Sets our color as the 'constant' variable
                constantColor [_Color]

                // Multiplies color (in constant) with texture
                combine constant * texture
            } 
        }
    }

    Fallback "Mobile/VertexLit"
}
```

Also you should use some texture, it can be 2x2 resolution white pixels. It will color the textures with exactly the same color as choosen in Trail Renderer.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing different material (regardless the no. of materials you added) and change the color to anything at least it's bright. Make sure you set the alpha to 255 to maintain visibility